# how to install the latest version of Tensorflow for CPU

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to install TensorFlow and I get this error when I try to import it :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

python version : 3.7.6

conda version : 4.8.1

tensorflow version: 2.1.0 (the latest)

conda packages have the same versions and Microsoft C++ Redist 2015 is installed

Comment: as far as i remember tensorflow doesn't work on python 3.7 or newer but it works on version 3.6. Try to install it on any 3.6 python version

Comment: The new version support python 3.7 .However, I tried that also and it didn't work. The output is just the same

Comment: See the release notes for 2.1.0 (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/RELEASE.md) and the part "Windows users: Officially-released tensorflow Pip packages are now built with Visual Studio 2019 version 16.4 in order to take advantage of the new /d2ReducedOptimizeHugeFunctions compiler flag. To use these new packages, you must install "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019", available from Microsoft's website here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads"

Comment: I tried that as well but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try installing or re-installing the C++ Redistributable from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads). Make sure you are downloading the "Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019" x64 version and restart your computer after the installation is complete.